# Obtains the name and ID of the dropped element

Tags: angular, typescript, drag-and-drop, angular-material, angular-cdk

I am using the cdk drag and drop library to drag and drop objects.

My problem is that I am not able to obtain the data (object information: name and ID) of the dropped object.

I've tried using `console.log (event.item.data)` but it gives undefined.

Does anyone know how I can get the information about the dropped element?

Thanks

[Stackblitz - Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wvvldc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**.ts**

```
 drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log(event.item.data)
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    }
  }
```

**html**

```
<div class="six" style=" height: 75%;">
  <div class="card-deck cardsZone">
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;"  #activeList="cdkDropList"
      class="box-list" style="height:100%"
      cdkDropList
      cdkDropListOrientation="vertical"
      [cdkDropListData]="A"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[inactiveList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let nw of A" cdkDrag>
        <div class="card mysmallCcards">             
          <div class="card-body">
                   <span>{{nw.name}}</span>         
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card myCards">
      <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;" #inactiveList="cdkDropList"
      class="box-list" style="height:100%"
      cdkDropList
      cdkDropListOrientation="vertical"
      [cdkDropListData]="B"
      [cdkDropListConnectedTo]="[activeList]"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
        <div *ngFor="let pr of B" cdkDrag>
        <div class="card mysmallCcards">
          <div class="card-body">
           <span>{{pr.name}}</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try with this `event.container.data[event.currentIndex]['id']`

Comment: So the id is the object that I replace, I want the id that I dragged and dropped. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try with this:

`event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]`

If you want the id of the item:

`event.previousContainer.data[event.previousIndex]['id]`

Answer (score 5):

The data of the item is just an input. The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api) for it is:

> @Input('cdkDragData') data: T
>
> Arbitrary data to attach to this drag instance.

So, to add the data to the event, you have to set it for each draggable element. Like this:

`<div *ngFor="let nw of A" cdkDrag [cdkDragData]="nw">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In the component, how can I use this?

Comment: @mark event.item.data

Answer (score 0):

Dragging within or across the container use `event.previousContainer.data[event.currentIndex]`

To get the item ID use `event.container.data[event.currentIndex]['id']`